# Unable to proxy a JBossMQ queue in Spring

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, lazy-loading, jbossmq

Spring JMS going against a JBoss 4.x JBossMQ queue (I know, old JBoss, JBossMQ superseded by JBoss Messaging, but I can't change the stack).  Everything works when the Spring JMS configuration is loaded at startup, but when I make the JNDI lookups lazy, so that they are first loaded when I want to send a JMS message, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Destination is not an instance of SpyDestination QUEUE.myQueueName; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Destination is not an instance of SpyDestination QUEUE.myQueueName
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:285)
```

My config:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="beanNameForMyQueue" 
    jndi-name="queue/myQueueName" 
    resource-ref="true" environment-ref="jndiEnvironment" 
    lookup-on-startup="false" cache="true" proxy-interface="javax.jms.Queue" />
```

I found a [JBoss JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-3035) on this, and this [similar HornetQ post](http://community.jboss.org/message/617161), but so far no dice.

Am I just out of luck with the lazy init, or is there a workaround?

Comment: From where does the call originate - is it in response to a web request?

Comment: Upstream, yes.  The point of the request is to make an asynch request bridging 2 servers.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I am running HornetQ and I am stuck on the same issue here.